# Where can I find 'Dolphin', the 3D model to LEGO software?

Tags: software, cad

It was created at the École Polytechique Fédérale de Lausanne.

But it seems it is no longer available for to download. Does anybody knows what happened?

Comment: Is is this that you are looking for?  http://lgg.epfl.ch/publications/2013/lego/ Description matches, but not the name (Dolphin)...

Comment: @Philo - this looks like the right answer, why don't you make it an actual answer?

Comment: There is this available from LEGO which may prove useful: http://ldd.lego.com/en-gb/

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for this: http://lgg.epfl.ch/publications/2013/lego/